# Unable to compile output of lex

Tags: gcc, lex, lexer

When I attempt to compile the output of this trivial lex program:

```
# lex.l
integer   printf("found keyword INT");
```

using:

```
$ gcc lex.yy.c
```

I get:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_yywrap", referenced from:
      _yylex in ccMsRtp7.o
      _input in ccMsRtp7.o
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

lex --version tells me I'm actually using 'flex 2.5.35' although ls -fla `which lex` isn't a symlink. Any ideas why the output won't compile?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [the Flex manual](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/I-get-an-error-about-undefined-yywrap_0028_0029_002e.html):

> ### I get an error about undefined yywrap().
>
> You must supply a yywrap() function of your own, or link to libfl.a (which provides one), or use
>
> ```
> %option noyywrap
> ```
>
> in your source to say you don't want a yywrap() function.

[Also:](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Generated-Scanner.html#index-yywrap_0028_0029)

> When  the  scanner receives an
>   end-of-file indication from
>          YY_INPUT,  it  then  checks  the    yywrap()  function.   If
>          yywrap() returns false (zero), then it is assumed that the
>          function has gone ahead    and  set  up  yyin  to  point  to
>          another input file, and scanning continues.  If it returns
>          true (non-zero), then the scanner terminates, returning    0
>          to its caller.  Note that in either case, the start condi-
>          tion remains unchanged; it does not revert to INITIAL.

Comment: +1 for mentioning linking with libfl.a, which provides a trivial `main()` as well as `yywrap()`: just build using `$ gcc lex.yy.c -lfl`.

Comment: In Mac, there is libl.a, which serves the same function as libfl.a, so compile with -ll

Answer (score 0):

As Eli's answer implies, that's not a trivial lex program.  It's a trivial lex *file*, and thus a portion of a program, but it (like any lex file) needs to be combined with some C code to make a complete program.  In particular, you still need a `main` function (which you write in C or C++ or something, in a separate file), and you will also need to write a `yywrap` function that provides the interface between the lex code and the rest of your C code.