# How does the C compiler parse the following C statement?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, printf, lexical-analysis

Consider the following lines:

```
int i;
printf("%d",i);
```

Will the lexical analyzer go into the string to parse `%` and `d` as separate tokens, or will it parse "%d" as one token?

Comment: lexical analyzer will identify `"%d"` as compete string. It is next phases of compiler "syntax" and "semantic" those identify missing argument and type check. If you compile code (without `i` in printf)  you will get warning `"format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument"` due to "syntax" and "semantic" checks.

Comment: how can a syntax analysis find an error if the string is not seperately parsed as token?

Comment: "syntax analysis" is next phase after "lexical". Compiler fist generates stream of tokens (as given in sepp2k's answer) then stream of tokes are further parsed (using grammar) and semantically checked in next phase.

Comment: Try [this code](http://codepad.org/LbDOEnzC) on your PC. You will get warning for second line print but not for `str = "%d"` that means compiler only parse `"%d"` when it is in printf - that indicates work is done after lexical phase

Comment: try [this trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612394/unable-to-compile-output-of-lex)

Comment: Lexical analysers don't parse anything. They scan it. Parsers parse. String literals are scanned without regard to the contents. The compiler doesn't know anything about `printf()` except for its presence, signature, and linkage.

Comment: I think you might be confusing terms -- when you say "one token" do you mean like how "\n" is parsed as a single character (even though you wrote two?) -- that is not the case for "%d" -- it gets parsed as two individual characters, since "%" is not an escape character that the compiler knows about / honors.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two parsers at work here: first, the C compiler, that will parse the C file and basically ignore the content of the string (though modern C compilers will parse the string as well to help catch bad format strings — mismatches between the `%` conversion specifier and the corresponding argument passed to `printf()` to be converted).

The next parser is the string format parser built into the C runtime library. This will be called at runtime to parse the format string when you call `printf`. This parser is of course very simple in comparison.

I have not checked, but I would guess that the C compilers that help checking for bad format strings will implement a `printf`-like parser as a post-processing step (i.e. using its own lexer).

Answer (score 19):

A string literal is a single token. The above code will be tokenized like this:

```
int     keyword "int"
i       identifier
;       semicolon
printf  identifier
(       open paren
"%d"    string literal
,       comma
i       identifier
)       closing paren
;       semicolon
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted to know more along the lines of will "%d" generate a char array with a length of 1, or 2 (i.e. "\n" would generate a char array with a length of 1) -- I think the answer he's looking for is that it would be a string literal with two distinct characters in it (that is then further parsed at run-time by the *printf method).

Answer (score 7):

`"%d"` is a *string literal* and it will be seen as one token by both the [C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) and also by the compiler, we can see this by going to [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.4` *Lexical elements* which defines the following tokens:

```
token:
  keyword
  identifier
  constant
  string-literal
  punctuator
```

and the following proprocessing tokens:

```
preprocessing-token:
  header-name
  identifier
  pp-number
  character-constant
  string-literal
  punctuator
  each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above
```

and says:

> A **token is the minimal lexical element** of the language in translation
>   **phases 7 and 8. The categories of tokens** are: keywords, identifiers,
>   constants, **string literals**, and punctuators. A preprocessing token is
>   the minimal lexical element of the language in translation **phases 3
>   through 6. The categories of preprocessing tokens are**: header names,
>   identifiers, preprocessing numbers, character constants, **string
>   literals**, punctuators, and single non-white-space characters that do
>   not lexically match the other preprocessing token categories.58) [...]

The different phases of translation are covered in section `5.1.1.2` *Translation phases* and I will highlight some of the relevant ones here:

> [...]
>
> 3 The source file is **decomposed into preprocessing tokens** 6) and sequences of
>   white-space characters (including comments).
>
> [...]
>
> 6 Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.
>
> 7 White-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant. **Each
>   preprocessing token is converted into a token**. The resulting tokens are
>   syntactically and semantically analyzed and translated as a translation unit.
>
> [...]

The distinction between *pre-processor tokens* and *tokens* may seem irrelevant but we can see that in at least one case such as in adjacent string literals for example `"%d" "\n"` you would have two *pre-processor tokens* while after phase `6` there would be only one *token*.