# Can't compile flex & bison (Symbols not found x86_64)

Tags: macos, bison, osx-yosemite, flex-lexer

I am trying to compile a simple program on Flex & Bison on my Mac running Yosemite but get the following error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_yyerror", referenced from:
      _yyparse in pr1-19c182.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

My two files look like this, they compile on my teacher's Ubuntu installation but I can't get them to work on my Mac:

pr1.y

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
%}

%%

expr : expr '+' term {printf(" + ");}
    | term 
    ;

term : term '*' fact {printf(" * ");}
    | fact 
    ;

fact : "(" expr ")"
    | '0' {printf("0");}
    | '1' {printf("1");}
    | '2' {printf("2");}
    | '3' {printf("3");}
    | '4' {printf("4");}
    | '5' {printf("5");}
    | '6' {printf("6");}
    | '7' {printf("7");}
    | '8' {printf("8");}
    | '9' {printf("9");}

%%
```

pr1.l

```
%{
    #include "pr1.tab.h"
%}

%%

[0-9]   {return (yytext[0]);}
[+*()]  {return (yytext[0]);}
\n      {return (0);}
.       {}

%%
```

I compile everything using the following commands:

```
bison -d pr1.y
flex pr1.l
gcc -o result lex.yy.c pr1.tab.c -lfl -std=gnu89
```

The reason I use the -std flag is because the default is c99 and the code generated by flex and bison gets warnings and errors. Any ideas???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define `yyerror` in your bison input file (`pr1.y`). And you need to declare `yylex` or you will get another warning.

The following would be fine:

```
%{
   #include <stdio.h>
   void yyerror(const char* msg) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
   }
   int yylex();
%}
```

I have no idea how it works without that on your teacher's machine.

Also, Mac OS X has very old versions of bison and flex. You might want to upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the 2nd comment of the answer on this post [Unable to compile output of lex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612394/unable-to-compile-output-of-lex)

On Mac OS X, if you're trying to compile from the command line, you need to link against the libl.a library, by using -ll instead of -lfl. Apparently OS X has no libfl.a library. So try this...

```
gcc -o result lex.yy.c pr1.tab.c -ll
```

Don't know about your need for the `-std=gnu89` option.